# Shopify Custom Configurable Product

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, e-commerce, shopify

I have an over the top vague question to ask any Shopify customers here...

Is there an app that allows you to set up a custom configurable product like the one shown here: http://www.eyeloveshadez.com/products/custom-sunglasses-and-diffraction

If not an app, maybe any direction just to start me down the right path? Very new to Shopify in general and I know it's not the most customizable e-commerce software out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by something called as line item properties.

[Get customization information for products](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/get-customization-information-for-products)

Comment: I'll run with this. Thank you!